# redirect user from php url to grails page

Tags: grails, filter, grails-2.0, action-filter

I am using grails 2.X.
when user hits on http://www.abcdef.com/redir/abc.php?id=123, i want to redirect user to some other url mappings like http://www.abcdef.com/abcd.

I already used grails filter but can't get appropriate solution.

Can anyone tell me how to do so using grails?
Do we need Filters or some scripts to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved in UrlMappings.groovy. This configuration should suit your needs:

```
"/$controller.$suffix" {
  constraints {
    suffix(matches: 'php')
  }
}
```

Comment: where will i write redirect code? "abcd" is my new redirection url.

Comment: into UrlMappings.groovy

Comment: i mean new redirection url, when it matched 'php' it should be redirect to appropriate url.

Comment: This is general configuration that maps *.php to *. For example it maps myController.php to controller "myController"